# Google Script to force new spreadsheet entries to start at Row 2 after running script to clear the range

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm an elementary teacher with limited coding experience but I enjoy trying to figure things out if it simplifies my life. :)

I created a Google Form for my students to make their daily lunch choice.

I set up a script that has a trigger to clear the form between midnight and 1 am each night, and it looks like this:

```
function clearRange() {
//replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Lunch');
sheet.getRange('A2:G25').clearContent();}
```

The script itself works - however, now, whenever new entries are added, they are added to the spreadsheet row right below where the old entries were cleared. Thus, if I have twenty students responding on Monday, the spreadsheet has rows 2-21 filled out, which get cleared sometime overnight Monday/Tuesday AM, and the next day, the responses fill rows 22-42, etc. etc.

How can I edit or add something to my script that forces it to put all new entries, after the old ones are cleared, on Row 2 of my spreadsheet?

If this question has already been answered, please point me in that direction as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us the code where you write on the Sheets using Appscript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of clearing content from cells, you need to delete rows containing form submission.

Here is the modified code which should work for you. Also, make sure you do not have any frozen row/s.

```
function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Lunch');

  //get last row, this will be used to count how many rows to delete
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();

  //delete row from 2 to last row
  sheet.deleteRows(2, lr-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the [.clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) method and Google Forms keeps track of the responses based on the row in your spreadsheet, you need to delete the row completely using [deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deleterowsrowposition-howmany), like this:

```
function clearRange() {
  //replace 'Sheet1' with your actual sheet name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Lunch');
  sheet.deleteRows(2, 25);
}
```

**Note:** This will not restart the counter you see in the Google Forms user interface:

[image]

In order to do that, you will need to use the [deleteAllResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#deleteAllResponses()) using the [FormApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-app)

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help!